# Create custom animated segue with images?

Tags: objective-c, animation, segue

I am trying to build a custom segue for an iOS app that utilizes images on the top and bottom of the screen (like a header and footer) that will slide up/down (out), transition to the next page, then slide back in. I found a simple tutorial that does the animation that I would like to use, but I am stuck trying to implement it into a segue.

Is this possible? If so, how? I have barely found any documentation on what I would like to do, and I am royally stuck!

Thanks in advance.

**Animation tutorial:** http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial

Comment: It should be noted that the tutorial you link yo is for a `UIView`, not a `UIViewController`. Segues make transitions between `UIViewControllers`... however things are a bit different in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### iOS 7

What you're asking about is possible with new APIs. However, iOS 7 is currently under NDA. Please avoid asking iOS 7 related questions on Stack Overflow until the SDK, Toolchain, and OS go final. Ask this question on the iOS Developer Forums. When iOS 7 becomes public, I'll edit this answer to describe how to do it.

Meanwhile (since you're a registered developer), I can point you to a few resources that may be of interest (you may need to sign in to access them).

- [WWDC Videos](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/)

  - The video titled [**Building User Interfaces for iOS 7**](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/#201) introduces the new Segue animations and techniques. The part of interest is around the 18:30 minute mark.
  - The video titled [**Custom Transitions using View Controllers**](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/#218) goes in depth to explain the new custom animated segues and how to use them.
- [Creating Custom Segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html) - Pre-release documentation
- [Posts about Segue's on the Dev Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/search.jspa?resultTypes=MESSAGE&peopleEnabled=true&q=segue) - Just search the Developer Forums

### iOS 5 - 6

Creating custom segues in earlier versions of iOS (5.0 and up) is fairly straightforward, unlike iOS 7 - the animations can't really interact with views within your `ViewController` and they aren't as dynamic.

To setup a custom segue, you'll need to first create a subclass of [uistoryboardsegue](/questions/tagged/uistoryboardsegue)  ([Documentation Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIStoryboardSegue)). Override the `perform` method and add your own animation and drawing code:

```
- (void)perform {
    //Add your own animation code here, then present the View Controller using that custom animation
    [[self sourceViewController] presentModalViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO];
}
```

Now that you've subclassed `UIStoryboardSegue` and created your own animation, you'll need to connect the segue in Interface Builder.

1. Create the Segue by Control-Dragging from the source view controller to the destination view controller.
2. Select `custom` from the list [image: Creating a Storyboard Segue]
3. Name the Segue by setting its Identifier (this way you can also call the segue using the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`) method. Then set the Segue Class to the name of your `UIStoryboardSegue` subclass.

   [image]

Comment: Ahh, you're absolutely correct! I'm glad you reminded me or else I would've gone on asking. Is there a simpler answer that you might recommend without targeting iOS7 in particular? In the meantime, I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Maegan Check out my edited answer with instructions on how to do this with iOS 5.0 and iOS 6.0

Comment: Thanks for your help! Looks like I'll have to dig a little deeper in the Apple community for what I want to do specifically, but this is definitely a start.